# Magento 1 and 2 extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, error, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I am migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2

So, I have a few questions.

1. Since magento 2 has fundamental changes I assume that copying the extensions (files and folders) from magento 1 to magento 2 won't work?
2. Is there a way to check what extensions are installed in magento 1? (I received the project from another person)
3. When migrating the data I get the following errors. These are probably because of the missing extensions?

> [2016-03-07 16:24:03][ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped: find_feed_import_codes,googlebase_attributes,googlebase_items,googlebase_types,interaktingslider_slide,interaktingslider_slide_position,interaktingslider_slide_sto
>
> re,saferpaynew_api_debug,smtppro_email_log,ugiftcert_cert,ugiftcert_history
>
> [2016-03-07 16:24:03][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_creditmemo. Fields:
>   giftcert_amount,base_giftcert_amount
>
> [2016-03-07 16:24:03][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document:
>   sales_flat_invoice. Fields: giftcert_amount,base_giftcert_amount
>
> [2016-03-07 16:24:03][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped.
>   Document: sales_flat_order. Fields:
>   giftcert_code,giftcert_amount,base_giftcert_amount,giftcert_amount_invoiced,base_giftcert_amount_invoiced,giftcert_amount_credited,base_giftcert_amount_credited
>
> [2016-03-07 16:24:03][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped.
>   Document: sales_flat_quote. Fields: giftcert_code
>
> [2016-03-07 16:24:03][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped.
>   Document: sales_flat_quote_address. Fields:
>   giftcert_amount,base_giftcert_amount,giftcert_code,base_giftcert_balances,giftcert_balances

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to RiccardoT and David Verholen. After updating the map.xml and config.xml The migrating is moving forward.

But now it is currently stuck at

EAV STep: `[2016-03-08 12:38:36][ERROR]: Source and Destination attributes mismatch. Attribute id: 383`

What does this error mean and how to fix it? I can't find the file to handle this error.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your questions:

**Number 1:**

Magento2 must be considered a different product from Magento1. So the extensions made form Magento1 will not work for Magento2.

**Number 2:**

You can check the files inside `etc/modules` or just check the admin page of your website in `System > Configuration > Advanced`. You will see a list of active modules.

**Number 3:**

Seems like a problem in the migration tool. Have a look in the Magento forum, the same problem is marked as solved: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/data-migration-tool-map-xml/td-p/23244

Comment: Just one addition to #2: this list also shows inactive modules. I recommend using the [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/) command line tool: `php n98-magerun.phar sys:modules:list`

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, magento1 extensions won't work in magento2. There is a migration tool but you still have to do many things by hand https://github.com/magento/code-migration
2. In the Magento Backend, under System -> Configuration -> Advanced you can see all installed Modules
3. The errors are from missing mappings for custom tables and custom fields in tables. To make it work, Magento needs to know what to do with those. Information on how to use the data migration tool can be found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html